# How to increase page timeout for

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I am writing some webdriver test and one of my test cases consistently times out in Firefox only. I am running into this exception when a page is loading. I am only running into this issue with Firefox, IE and Chrome are not having this issue. As this page historically takes a while to load and over 1 min is not out of the ordinary how can I increase this timeout to say 2 min? I have already set the Driver.Manage().Timeout().SetPageLoadTimeout() to 3 min. But still see this timeout after only 1 min. When watching the test run it appears that the page is waiting to fully load before but why then is it timing out at 1 min rather than 3?

```
Result Message: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:7055/hub/session/3e09453d-26bb-4a6c-9f23-9cae9fc1ed60/element/%7B841d23a5-2842-4dec-a5d3-9575bc068e47%7D/click timed out after 60 seconds.
  ----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out
Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Click()
   at POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite.NewUserTestSuite`1.TokenizeNewAccount() in c:\Users\jburns\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\POMAuctivaTest\POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite\NewUserTestSuite.cs:line 97
   at POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite.NewUserTestSuite`1.RegisterAndActivateNewUser() in c:\Users\jburns\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\POMAuctivaTest\POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite\NewUserTestSuite.cs:line 74
--WebException
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
```

Comment: Selenium WebDriver 2.48 supports till firefox version 41.0.

Comment: maybe the problem is not in the page loading, is in the javascript performance. In this case, use `SetScriptTimeout `

Comment: This morning I tried bumping the SetScriptTimeout up to 3 min and still saw test timeout at the same spot with the same 'timed out after 60 seconds'. I also tired setting the ImplicityWait time to 2 min in case it was looking for an element. Both did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Well I found a solution to my issue, it was not a solution to increasing the timeout that I was triggering. But my workaround was to use the GetAttribute() on the button that triggered the page load to get the href. And then use Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(). To navigate this worked as now I can see the 3 min SetPageLoadTimeout() limit being honored.